# Objective-C 'CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got this warning:

```
'CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use [NSString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:] instead, which always uses the recommended UTF-8 encoding, and which encodes for a specific URL component or subcomponent (since each URL component or subcomponent has different rules for what characters are valid).
```

on this line:

```
return (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)self, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ", CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
```

I tried to google for a solution, but I just didn't understand anything. Please Help.

I have tried the following:

```
return [NSString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:(NULL, (CFStringRef)self, (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ", CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding))];
```

and got this new warning:

```
Class method '+stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

and

```
Expression result unused
```

Comment: Use `[NSString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:]` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to sound rude, but have you ever written a single line of Objective-C?

Comment: I do find that rude. I have but im not good at code coverting

Comment: Please look at the docs for `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:`.  It isn't a class method and it takes one parameter, which is a `NSCharacterSet`.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I'll take a swing:

```
- (NSString *)escaped
{
#if (TARGET_OS_MAC && (MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED > MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_9))
    NSString * encodedString = (NSString *)
    CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapes(
                                               NULL,
                                               (CFStringRef)self,
                                               NULL);
#else
    NSString * encodedString = (NSString *)
    CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
        NULL,
        (CFStringRef)self,
        NULL,
        (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
        kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
#endif
    return encodedString;
}
```